# Localhost router

Tags: localhost

здраствуйте есть проблемма не получается зайти по айпи на локальный сайт с компьютеров по локальной беспроводной сети порты 80 и 443 прописаны в брандмауэере роутер зиксель система виндовс 7 сеть общественая в другой почти такой же сети все работает только там не зиксель а тп-линк кто нибудь может помочь? заранее благодарен и еще с самого сервера открывается по адресу 192.168.1.30 а с клиентских пишет не удалось открыть веб страницу

Comment: telnet ip-adress 80, telnet ip-adress 443 работает?

Comment: да и пингуется по ip адресам только вот еще заметил что ip беспроводного подключения совпадает с ip DHCP оба 192.168.1.33 и меняется как только поменяю адрес на сервере а адрес локальной сети 192.168.1.46 но там не открывается локальный сайт

Comment: а что есть "локальный сайт"? может сайт не до настроен?

Comment: Что-то я не уловил... Нужен доступ из глобальной сети на сайт, расположенный локально за Zyxel-ем, так?А на Zyxel-е порты проброшены? Или DMZ настроена? А сайт в NDS прописан? А какая ОСь под сайтом? А какой HTTP-сервер под сайтом?Побольше информации, если можно. ---ЗЫИ, да, - не пренебрегайте знаками препинания... Читать противно, уж простите...

Comment: локальный сайт это апач,нет на самом сервере все открывается а для клиентских компов я незнаю как настраивать, из за этого и обратился сюда за помощью специалистов

Comment: но в другой сети все открывается без всяких настроек

Comment: на всех компах виндоус 7 включая сервер, порты наверно проброшены (если это очзначает добавить правило в исключениях брандмауера) DMZ хмммм звучит красиво DNS сервер 192.168.1.33 доступ нужен ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ не глобальный, в других двух локальных сетях можно заходить написав айпи адрес/сайт без всяких настроек черртт уже полдня ищу выход

Comment: если вы разбираетесь в настройках роутера можете помочь? тут по моему дело вот в чем - компьютеру подключенному по wifi присваивается тот же самый ip что и серверу DHCP то есть 192.168.1.33 и он кажется ищет у себя ,у него же тоже такой адрес а поменять незнаю как там же по автомату, а если менять в настройках сервера там тоже меняется

Comment: Ну так поставить статический адрес у клиентского компютера надо попробовать.

Comment: * Если сайт локальный - то вам ни DMZ, ни проброс портов не нужны.* Брандмауэр - в сад!* IP хоста с сайтом - в резервирование DHCP (если получает от него), чтоб другим не повадно было. В оптимале - адреса ВСЕХ и ЛЮБЫХ серверов выносить ЗА пределы диапазона адресов DHCP. Странно, что вообще выдает занятый адрес... * DHCP на ВСЕМ, кроме сервера DHCP (включая точки доступа), настроить так, чтоб диапазоны основного и дополнительных DHCP-серверов НЕ ПЕРЕСЕКАЛИСЬ.* На DNS-сервере добавить узел с IP хоста сайта и именем сайта.ЗЫ Вообще-то, азы...ЗЗЫ МОДЕЛЬ СЕТИ В СТУДИЮ

Comment: ...продолжу.* если нет DNS-сервера - IP хоста сайта прописать ручками в файле hosts пользователей сайта.* > без всяких настроекэто так кажется... Спросить у того, кто делал.* много читать, учить русский язык, злоупотреблять знаками препинания!!!ЗЫ Вообще-то, азы...ЗЗЫ МОДЕЛЬ СЕТИ В СТУДИЮ

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо но они уже нашли какого то сисадмина который все наладил

Comment: Так а что было то в итоге? Анонимусу интересно!

Comment: в итоге было очень интересно!! меня хотели уволить ) да и сейчас кажется думают об этом, до конца недели будет ясно так и сказали